# Launchpad pbuilderrc settings

Tags: launchpad, pbuilder

I have a custom package I want to publish via launchpad. In order to build it, I need the `USENETWORK` option to be enabled (this way build-tools have network access, which is required in my case). On my local machine, I can enable this by adding it to the `pbuilderrc` file.

But how can this be done for the builds pushed to launchpad? I couldn't find anything related to that on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, I found that it is possible to set the following option to the `debuild` step. Remember that it is possible to add options to debuild through the `pbuilder` variable `--debbuildopts='--set-env="whatever=0"'`.

> --preserve-env
>
> Do not clean the environment, except for PATH.
>
> --preserve-envvar=var, -evar
>
> Do not clean the var variable from the environment. If var ends in an asterisk ("*") then all variables with
> names that match the portion of var before the asterisk will be
> preserved.
>
> --set-envvar=var=value, -evar=value
>
> Set the environment variable var to value and do not remove it from the environment.

This is taken from the [debuild manual](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/devscripts/debuild.1.en.html).

Comment: And how can this help? USENETWORK is not an environment variable, but a configuration

Comment: Then I do not understand what you want. An example of how you set this configuration on your machine would help.

Comment: I set it in the pbuilderrc file (See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/pbuilderrc.5.html). For my case it's the user variant, i.e. `~/.pbuilderrc` - but it behaves the same as the global one from the link.

Comment: did you try using `--set-env="USENETWORK=yes"'` ?